# How to workaround TFS 2013 RunMSBuild Activity Required OutDir Argument to Allow Project OutDir to Work?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

There are times that TFS's shared output folder is disruptive. In cases where I need a specific project's output directed to it's own isolated folder, I've come up with a solution whereby a custom WF activity parses the sln proj's and looks for proj names that match a given argument list and edit them at server build time to inject an OutDir property for the given platform|configuration that matches the proj name. i.e. (localServerPath)\bin\projName instead of just \bin.

This worked swimmingly using the 2010 MSBuild Activity because that activity allowed for an empty OutDir argument, thus allowing my proj level OutDir's to do their job. In the 2013 RunMSBuild activity, an empty OutDir argument throws errors, and if I prlovide it, all my proj level OutDir args are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ignore the OutDir Argument to make the RunMSBuild Activity worked.

However, you can try to use another way to customizable Output Directories for TFS Build. You just need three steps Create Workflow Parameter--Add Functionality to the Workflow-- Opt-In for Visual Studio Projects. More detailed info about how to achieve, please refer this [link](http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/31/Customizable+Output+Directories+For+TFS+2010+Build.aspx).